# Fail to deploy custom image classification model (TFLITE)

Tags: android, tensorflow, image-processing

I just trained a single-label image classification model using Google AutoML, but fail to use it in the Android phone. I modified the code and replaced my custom model into the example TensorFlow model from https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android according to https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tflite-android-tutorial. However, the app continue to crash and show that it is out of date.

Here are the errors in the logcat:

```
8472-8483/? E/flitecameradem: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
8472-8472/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
8472-8472/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
8472-8472/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
8472-8496/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
8472-8472/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
8472-8714/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.hal1.packagelist"
8472-8496/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
8472-8496/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
8472-8472/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
8472-8762/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.camera.legacy_perf"
8472-8713/android.example.com.tflitecamerademo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
Process: android.example.com.tflitecamerademo, PID: 8472
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:542)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.putFloat(DirectByteBuffer.java:802)
    at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.convertBitmapToByteBuffer(ImageClassifier.java:195)
    at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.ImageClassifier.classifyFrame(ImageClassifier.java:113)
    at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.classifyFrame(Camera2BasicFragment.java:663)
    at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment.access$900(Camera2BasicFragment.java:69)
    at com.example.android.tflitecamerademo.Camera2BasicFragment$5.run(Camera2BasicFragment.java:558)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Answer (score 2):

To fix the `BufferOverflowException` error you also have to change how you put values in the `imgData` buffer. 
Since we changed `imgData` to contain bytes instead of floats, we also need to replace `putFloat` with `put` in the method `convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap)`:

```
imgData.put((byte) ((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD));
imgData.put((byte) ((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD));
imgData.put((byte) ((((val) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD));
```